# 2020 Macbook Pro won't connect to HDMI on Promethean Board

Tags: display, usb, hardware, hdmi

I have a Macbook Pro (2020) running Big Sur 11.7.4

I have tried two USB - C to HDMI adapters to run the display to a Promethean Board in a classroom

One was an apple-branded multifunction adapter (has USB C to HDMI and USB and one other that escapes me at the moment). The other is a USB-C to HDMI only adapter.

The Promethean board says it detects the input from HDMI. Well and good, but then it displays "no signal"

When I open the Display preferences there doesn't seem to be an indicator that the Board is even there...

The wireless display works (I have a screen share app) but that won't go to 2 boards at once, and that was what I wanted to do (this is because of the physical configuration of the room). Granted it isn't *absolutely* necessary. But I would like to be able to hard-connect the computer to an external display now and again. It was ok to run one display wireless and the other with the hard connection. In any case I thought it odd that the USB C to HDMI suddenly stopped working with the new OS (it worked before I updated).

Any ideas as to what is happening here?

Comment: Do the adapters work ok on any other HDMI device, and how long is your HDMI cable?